# Ecto use multiple nodes

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a replicated PostgreSQL database, with a master and two replicas.

I want Ecto to use master for write queries, and use slaves (maybe along with master) for reading ones, possibly with a weight option to balance queries.

Is this achievable through configuration? I can't seem to find it in documentation or by googling.

I'm using Ecto 2.1.

Comment: I don't think it is possible directly in Ecto / PostgreSQL. Though there are some tools listed on https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling that can act as a sql proxy to master and replicas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not by configuration. But you can define multiple repos in your config and use the different repos in the select statements [sample](https://edmz.org/personal/2016/03/09/multiple_databases_with_ecto_and_phoenix.html). At least this will help you direct the read- and write-statements to two different nodes.

Comment: This will do when you have a static number of replicas. It will not be useful when you need to dynamically change configuration.

Comment: Sure, if you want to spread the load over the read replicas you should use a load balancer which is not necessarily part of your elixir app.

Comment: It creates a bit more complex setup for a two-replica app, to start. Thank you anyway!